# Why don't we have to create object of System or Math classes in java and use them directly?

Tags: java, class, system

We use System.out.println without instantiating it or creating object of it. Same goes to Math class and many others (I guess). Is there something special about these classes? Can we use the classes and methods declared within those classes in same fashion? Please help.

Comment: I think you are asking why this class API's are kept static instead of instance, is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create objects for the `System` and `Math` classes because the methods and variables in those classes are `static`. This means that they belong to the class itself, not to *instances* of the class.

For reference see:

- [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)
- [Beyond Basic Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/beyondmath.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is something called 'static' method. In order to invoke static method, you do not need to have an instance of the class.

This also has other side effects such as non-existing 'this' and thus static methods cannot invoke instance methods.

This is mostly used for some sort of utility classes which are often stateless.

Math is a good example for it.

I suggest to read a bit about static methods and static in Java in general.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't we have to create object of System or Math classes in java and use them directly?

Because the methods of `Math` are declared as `static` methods, and because `System.in` / `System.out`  / `System.err` are `static` variables.

> Is there something special about these classes?

No.  Any variables or methods that are declared as `static` will behave that way.

> Can we use the classes and methods declared within those classes in same fashion?

I don't really understand what you are asking there.   But, if you are asking if you can create an instance of `Math` or `System` so that you can do something like this:

```
    Math myMath = new Math();
    myMath.min(1, 2);
```

1. No, you can't.  Neither of those classes has a public constructor, so you can't `new` them.
2. And if you could do that, it would be really bad style!

Reference:

- [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my last question. I meant to ask, Can we use classes and methods we create ourselves in the same fashion such as System.out.println and so on... I guess your answer is yes, as long as we define the methods and member variables as static?

Comment: Yes.  You have got it.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to create object of `System` and `Math` class to use it because they have **static methods**. Static methods belong to the class and thus doesn’t require it to be instantiated.

Although, you can create its object and then also use those methods, but creating a class for static method is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

First,you cannot make an instance of the class Math,because it has only a single constructor and it's been marked private and you just can't make an instance  of it from outside the class.
[Snapshot of the source code of the class Math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waRUJ.jpg)
Second,you don't need to do that.All of the methods in class Math are static,just use the class name and the dot operator and you can invoke any one of them.

Answer (score 1):

System class can't instantiate/create object because this System class have private constructor.
And it's all members and methods are static, that can be accessible directly by Class name.
this simple and valid answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

We don't instantiate every other class or method because the JVM(Java Virtual Machine) already loads them into the project and hence, we can use these classes again and again. One such example is the main method. These classes/methods are already predefined for us so there is no need for us to instantiate such classes/methods because they are static.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to instantiate the object in order to use methods of the `math` class.

- Because to use this methods we don't need object. We can directly invoke this.
- These type of classes are called `static`. Here methods can directly invoked by the class itself.
- They are already defined in the `JVM`. We don't need to instantiate to use methods of this class.